# Update New value by checking OLD Value in AFTER Update Statement using MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, laravel, triggers

I have a two different database tables

```
database: test1 -> table: customer
database: test2 -> table: customer_data
```

customer

```
id  email
1   test@test.com
2   test@gmail.com
3   test@yahoo.com
```

customer_data

```
id params
1   test@gmail.com
2   test@yahoo.com
3   test@test.com
```

When user update customer email address for example,
for id =1
I want to create trigger which check
if customer_data table has
params = test@test.com
update it to new one using trigger

Code I tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_customer_email_update AFTER UPDATE ON customer_data 
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE customer_data
    SET params = NEW.email
    WHERE params = OLD.email;
 END
```

But not updating record in another database table!!

Comment: You probably should be more descriptive than 'not working' in your question too. It looks too much like a newbie question and you're obviously not.

Comment: @danblack: Updated question

Comment: Your code MUST report about syntax error (because you have BEGIN without END). `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6`. And the trigger is not created at all.

Comment: I am only getting SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test2.customer' doesn't exist

Comment: If server reports that the table does not exist then either it not exists really or you have no privileges to access it.

Comment: @Akina because tables are in two different databases

Comment: They're in different databases on the same MySQL instance?

Comment: @Akina yes it is in on same instance

Comment: If so then check privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the trigger on the wrong table, and also the logic of the update is not correct.  Try this version:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_customer_email_update AFTER UPDATE ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    UPDATE customer_data
    SET params = NEW.email
    WHERE params = OLD.email
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @Akina two ids are not related so i can't use ids in where condition

Comment: @BhumiShah Then your table design is not optimal.  In this case, I think the only major problem was your definition of the trigger on the wrong table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER after_customer_email_update 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE customer_data
    SET params = NEW.email
    WHERE params = OLD.email;
```

PS. Single-statement trigger (any compound statement) does not need in BEGIN-END and DELIMITER reassign (they're excess, but you may use them nevertheless).

[image]